# grail upgrade error - creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor'

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails

I am working with GGTS and using Hibernate as a dB and I'm upgrading from Grails 2.3.3 to 2.5.1 - I get this error when running run-app on the project. I have read a number of posts regarding similar transactionManager problems but none seem to match my situation closely enough. Here is the initial part of the error message related to transactionManagerPostProcessor:

> context.GrailsContextLoaderListener Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean '$primaryTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '$primaryTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean '$primaryTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '$primaryTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory]

Since all signs are this problem relates to setting up the databases here is the DataSource.groovy:

`
    System.out.println("datasource.groovy: Hello World....?")

```
    dataSource {
pooled = true

driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"

username = "sa"
password = "S2xxxxxxxx"
}

dataSource_publish {

pooled = true    
driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
username = "sa"
password = "M1xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = true
cache.use_query_cache = false

//cache.region.factory_class = 'grails.plugin.cache.ehcache.hibernate.BeanEhcacheRegionFactory' // For Hibernate before 4.0 and higher  
//cache.region.factory_class = 'grails.plugin.cache.ehcache.hibernate.BeanEhcacheRegionFactory' // For Hibernate before 4.0 and higher  
//cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' //old vers of hibernate

cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
development {

    // The main HomeVu dB
     dataSource {
        logSql = false
        pooled = true
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:h2:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
    }

     // The SHR shared dB
     dataSource_publish {
     //logSql = false
     //pooled = true
     dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
     //url = "jdbc:h2:pubDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
     //url = "jdbc:h2:pb1Db;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT10000; AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
     url = "jdbc:h2:pub009Db;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
     }



}
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
    }
}
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        pooled = true
        properties {
           maxActive = -1
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
           numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
           testOnBorrow=true
           testWhileIdle=true
           testOnReturn=true
           validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        }
    }
}
```

}
`

I have used the recommended versions of the plugins as set out in the release notes - here is my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
System.out.println("BuildConfig.groovy: Hello World....?")
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container     compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.work.dir = 'target'
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.server.port.http=9000

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // MAK 12-05-16 put in to link in spring-security-core plugin
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to  disable ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log 'debug' // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    mavenLocal()

    mavenCentral()

    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories

    mavenRepo "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"

    grailsRepo "http://grails.org/plugin"


}
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

   }

plugins {

    // Requested in grail version 2.5.1 ...
    build(":release:3.1.1",
        ":rest-client-builder:2.1.1") {
      export = false
        }

    compile ":hibernate:3.6.10.19"

    runtime ":jquery:1.11.0.2"

    build ":tomcat:7.0.55.3"

    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"

    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ':asset-pipeline:2.1.5'

    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"

}
```

}

Perhaps jumping Grails versions in this way rather then incrementally upgrading means that I've left some legacy settings that needs to be modified? I
would welcome any suggestions?

-mike

Answer (score 1):

I can see hibernate 3.x in your BuildConfig, but region factory class is set to one that is proper for hibernate 4.
Try to change class name assigned to `cache.region.factory_class`

```
cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
// cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
```